# Error when running "gans/experiments/emnist:run_experiments" using Bazel: The 'run' command is only supported from within a workspace

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-federated

I failed running "bazel run tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist:run_experiments", which gives me the error: "The 'run' command is only supported from within a workspace (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file)."

[Error Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjg1.png)

There is a WORKSPACE empty file in my "federated" git repo, and I run "touch WORKSPACE".
[My git repo folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQwgA.png)

My test of installation by running "python -c "import tensorflow_federated as tff; print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello World')())" succeeds.

I can also run "bazel run tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist:train".

Here is my configuration:

Python 3.6.9

Tensorflow 2.2.0

Tensorflow-Federated 0.16.1

Bazel 3.4.1

I build the TensorFlow Federated python package from source using Bazel from this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/install.md#build-the-tensorflow-federated-python-package-from-source

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, did you follow [the previous step describing how to download and `cd` into the `tensorflow/federated` project directory?](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/install.md#3-clone-the-tensorflow-federated-repository) It does appear to be necessary to be inside that directory when running the provided `bazel` command.